# How to access data from ozone using flink?

Tags: apache-flink, ozone

*When I use Flink to access the ozone file system, I configure the relevant configuration files and place the relevant jars in the hadoop classpath. An error is reported when accessing the file system using wordcount.*

environment:

- hadoop3.2.2
- Flink1.12.1
- Ozone1.2.1
- JDK1.8

But if I execute `hadoop fs -ls ofs://jykj0.yarn.com/` alone there is no problem.

Below is my config file core-site.xml：

```
<property>
  <name>fs.ofs.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneFileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.ofs.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.OzoneFileSystem</value>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.ozone.RootedOzoneFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flink currently doesn't support Ozone. There is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28231 which you can track for potentially adding support for this.